# Jenkins ssh-steps-plugin

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to manage 1000 nodes through CI/CD pipeline so I came across 'ssh-steps-plugin' which can help me in my requirement but don't know how to use this plugin. Highly appreciate any tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started using this plugin too. The [plugin GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin) repository has a good documentation on what the plugin is capable of.

Even there's [an example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin#examples) using `withCredentials` to use a SSH Key to log into your remotes.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go through the documentation.